# How to use updateActivity (php lib)

Tags: getstream-io

I have activity with and without foreign_id.
How to update Activity (example to change one field, "tweet": "hi1" to "tweet": "hi2") ?

Comment: Start with reading [tour] and [mcve]

Comment: this would help us too , [`How do I ask a good question?`](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: you need to add activities with both foreign_id and time if you want to update them later

Comment: `{
"actor": "George",
"foreign_id": "test",
"object": "",
"to": [],
"tweet": "Cool",
"verb": "say"
}`
Then i send activity in updateActivity method with current time and foreign_id
`{
"actor": "George",
"foreign_id": "test",
"object": "",
"to": [],
"tweet": "Not cool",
"verb": "say",
"time": "{{time in format like IntegrationFeedTest}}"
}`

Answer (score 0):

Per Tommaso's feedback in a comment above, when you send a foreign_id and timestamp in your activity, you must pass back the same foreign_id and exact timestamp for the update to take effect. If you change the timestamp in your update, it will not update the original activity.